# Magento {{depend}} combined with {{config path='some/value/here'}}

Tags: email-templates, transactional

we are using the {{depend}} functionality to check for true on a system config variable

But now we are running into the following. Can I combine these special {{}} tags within each other? For example if I want to check config path='some/value/here' to be TRUE, would I do it as follows?

```
{{depend {{config path='some/value/here'}}}} text here
```

Question: How can I use the depend to check a config path value?

And maybe a second question is: does depend check for empty, or does it also understand yes and no's from the config?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `{{depend}}` and `{{config}}` in that combination for 2 reasons.
The first and most important is that the regex match is screwed up like this. If you have a text like this `{{depend name}} some text {{/depend}}` the matches array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {{depend name}} some text {{/depend}}
            [1] => name
            [2] =>  some text 
        )

)
```

This means that if the value for the variable `name` evaluates to something else than `null` `false` `0` the value in [0] (the expression) will be replaced with the value from [2] (some text).
If you try it with `{{depend {{config path="some/path/here"}}}} some text {{/depend}}` the matches look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {{depend {{config path='some/path/here'}}}} some text {{/depend}}
            [1] => {{config path='some/path/here'
            [2] => }} some text 
        )

)
```

The second reason is that the depend conditions must be a variable passed to the template (element inside the `_templateVars` member).
The work around for this is to pass the value from the config as a variable to the template and then use that variable in the `depend` statement.
Let's take for example the new order e-mail sending. In `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail()`

```
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
    'order'        => $this,
    'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
    'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
    )
);
```

Turn it into this:

```
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
    'order'        => $this,
    'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
    'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
    'my_config_var'=> Mage::getStoreConfig('some/path/here')
    )
);
```

Now you should be able to use:

```
{{depend my_custom_var}} some text {{/depend}}
```

Comment: Many thanks Marius. Now we are creating a simple extension that actually only adds some fields in config via system.xml : the question is how would I add this to the extension? (not touching core or other files) .... major thanks

Comment: @snh_nl I think this is the subject of an other question. Ask an other one. Anyway... read this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/admin/xml_structure_for_admin_configurations

Comment: I have read it before ... but can't find the answer here. thanks

Comment: ASked another: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6547/magento-extension-make-config-available-for-email-templates